# Approach for secure API keys on Web Assembly WASM SPA's? Client or Server?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, webassembly, adyen

I have a functioning WASM (Blazor) SPA and I want to add payments to it.
Obviously this requires the use of secure API keys and so I don't think they should be stored in the App itself..

I am debating with myself and have a couple of choices. I can:

a. Run the payment process on a (say) Razor Page on the server and somehow, get the result back to the client.
or

b. run the payment (JS drop-in) on the client, but go and get the API keys from the server as they are being used and delete them afterwards.

I am favouring b. but wondering if that is going to open up some massive security hole I am not aware of?

If I use a. I can get to a razor page on the server ok. But I think that will lose the application flow and not be a great user experience.

Which approach should I use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: The set of API keys should never be exposed on the client side. It should be part of your server that handles the requests from the client.

> I am debating with myself and have a couple of choices. I can:
>
> a. Run the payment process on a (say) Razor Page on the server and somehow, get the result back to the client. or

Your client should communicate with your backend that holds your API keys. You can find an example of the `sessions`-endpoint in C# on [github/adyen-example](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments/blob/main/checkout-example/Controllers/ApiController.cs#L32).

In the [WebhookController](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments/blob/main/checkout-example/Controllers/WebhookController.cs), you can also find the example on how to receive notifications on your backend

> b. run the payment (JS drop-in) on the client, but go and get the API keys from the server as they are being used and delete them afterwards.
> This is a no-go. You should never expose your API keys here.

Here's a flow chart that gives a nice overview of the flow [image: flow-chart of dropin]

*Taken from: https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in#how-it-works*

The 'Merchant Client' is where you should have the Web-dropin. You can serve your content from your Blazor server to the client here.

The 'Merchant Server' is where you handle your API keys safely as well as where you get your webhooks from the Adyen server.

Comment: Ok, so the drop in itself doesn't have any of my Keys accessible via the session data that is passed in?

It was this concern that made me think I should possibly run the drop in on a page in the server ...

Comment: The drop-in uses the payment session data to make the payment request (to your server) + handles any other actions such as redirects or 3D Secure authentication.

Comment: Looks like @KwokHe figured this out and reached the same conclusion I did. There seems to be a public key for the browser-based code and a private key for the server-based code. TBH I'm not sure what the point of the public key is exactly but at least it appears they are not expecting you and in fact are telling you not to give the browser any secret.

Comment: The clientKey usage can be found here: https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/client-side-authentication. The client key is a public key that uniquely identifies an API credential. Each API credential has a list of allowed origins, or domains from which we expect to get your requests. We make sure data cannot be accessed by unknown parties by using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Answer (score 2):

A Blazor SPA presents all the same security concerns as any other SPA or a desktop app. You always have to assume that the client app can and will be compromised. Like they told Indiana Jones, "trust no one!"

If you fetch the key from the server, it will be visible through the browser debugger when inspecting the API calls. The only way to keep it safe is to keep it server side. So you basically need to make another API layer just for your SPA and have that be a go-between to your *real* APIs. Otherwise if your SPA has access to it, so does the world. In other words, go with (a) but it doesn't have to be a Razor page. It can just be a private API dedicated to your SPA.

Comment: Hmmm.. thats what I was thinking.. though I do need to use a razor page or similar if I am going to use the  payment providers drop-in js code... which interestingly does stop you using the browser debugger, however I am sure thats not bullet proof...

Comment: @BrettJB Well be very careful to distinguish between serving files and pages (MVC views, JS files, etc.) and an API controller. Those two roles can be put on one ASP.NET Core application, sure, but you just need to be very aware of the difference. It's fine to host javascript code and other files on the server and have your SPA reference them. But just don't embed any secret keys in any code that gets downloaded. Instead make API controller method(s) that your SPA calls, and then those methods in turn call the "real" APIs, server-to-server. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also I don't know what you mean by some JS code "stop[s] you using the browser debugger" but you are correct, it is 100% *not* bullet proof. Anything that gets downloaded from server to client is not secret. Period, end of sentence, just assume that and make peace with it. So if you have a secret API key, don't ever let it leave your server. Use the fundamental theorem of computer science - another layer of indirection! - in this case, an intermediary API.

Comment: I'm guessing the drop in code you're referencing is intended to be run in server side Node.js rather than client side. If it uses a secret key then I'd be almost certain of it.

Comment: I am not sure tbh, but if the Adyen drop in is on a page and you try to debug it with chrome debug tools, it effectively blocks the browser which shows 'No Internet' .. 
I got to it a different way and was able to see what was going on for a short while, but then it 'stopped' after about 20 secs... Some kind of Singal R error. So its either clever intent or happy accident with this particular drop in...

Comment: Is it this? https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/additional-use-cases/advanced-flow/tutorial-node-js. They say there's a private API key that lives server side and a public key that is client side. If that's the case then they have already worked this out for you and you should be fine as long as you follow their instructions.